# Github API Error: Problems parsing JSON when following a user Swift 5

Tags: swift, alamofire, github-api, swift5

I am able to successfully login with github api on swift 5 with Alamofire but i have been struggling following a user for 2 days.

I am getting an error even though I have done every step in the [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#follow-a-user)

Here is my code:

```
func followUser(accessToken: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
    let parameters = ["user": "follow"]
    let headers : HTTPHeaders =
    [
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
        "Content-Length": "0",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "token \(accessToken)"
    ]
    AF.request("https://api.github.com/user/following/jake", method: .put, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let data):
            let outputStr  = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
            print("data \(outputStr!)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And i am getting this error:

```
 {"message":"Problems parsing JSON",
"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#follow-a-user"}
```

Comment: Remove `let parameters = ["user": "follow"]`.

Comment: @Larme now i am gettin {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#follow-a-user"}

Comment: Hod did you do remove it? You remove it there: `AF.request("https://api.github.com/user/following/jake", method: .put, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responeData {...` => `AF.request("https://api.github.com/user/following/jake", method: .put,  headers: headers).responeData {...`?

Comment: yes, i removed the "let parameters = ["user": "follow"]" and also removed from request line @Larme

Comment: I tested your code (and with removing `parameters`), and got it work. I followed briefly user @jake.

Comment: @Larme  can you please share with me the whole code or project?  maybe i the issue is about the token or something

Comment: It's the same code code as you gave, I copy/pasted and remove `parameters`.